# Rails: What's a good way to deal with empty params array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In one of my views I have a form that will send data to the controller.

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

<% for committee in @committees %>
  <div>
    <%= check_box_tag "user[relevant_committee_ids][]", committee.id, @user.relevant_committees.include?(committee) %>
    <%= committee.name %>
  </div>

<% end %>
  <%= f.submit t(:save_settings) %>
<% end %>
```

If the form is empty, no params[:user] is generated which will lead the following code in my controller to fail:

```
@user.relevant_committee_ids = params[:user][:relevant_committee_ids] ||= []
```

With the error message:

> You have a nil object when you didn't
>   expect it! You might have expected an
>   instance of Array. The error occurred
>   while evaluating nil.[]

What's a nice, readable way to get an empty array if params[:user] is not generated?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
@user.relevant_committee_ids = params[:user] ? params[:user][:relevant_committee_ids] : []
```

Answer (score 0):

My try would be:
`params[:user] ||= []
@user.relevant_committee_ids = params[:user][:relevant_committee_ids]
@user.relevant_committee_ids ||= []`

Generally, I find it's readable enough to use `x ||= []` syntax everywhere I must emphasize that I substitute empty collection for a nil value.

Answer (score 0):

`@user.relevant_committee_ids = params[:user].try(:[], :relevant_committee_ids) || []`